# iOS: apportable debug errors wit AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, apportable

I'm running an app with appportable and I have these errors after build my app:

```
In file included from /Users/.../Desktop/.../.../..././AFNetworking.h:40:
/Users/.../Desktop/.../.../.../AFURLSessionManager.h:153:1: error: property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t completionQueue;
^
/Users/.../Desktop/.../.../.../AFURLSessionManager.h:158:1: error: property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_group_t completionGroup;
^
/Users/.../Desktop/.../.../.../AFURLSessionManager.h:207:52: error: expected a type
                                         progress:(NSProgress * __autoreleasing *)progress
```

I read that in AFNetworkActivityLogger I should set s.ios.deployment_target = '6.0' but it's ok, I don't understand the problem

Answer (score 2):

I believe completionQueue and completionGroup are not objects. So remove "strong" from both of them. eg:

```
@property (nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t completionQueue;

@property (nonatomic) dispatch_group_t completionGroup;
```

As for the Third error, I think you will need to pass an object with type **NSProgress *** to that function. You must have pass the wrong object.

Can you show some code? I can not know for a certain without the code.

Comment: the code is in AFNetworking framework not in my code

Comment: in AFURLSessionManager.h

Comment: Then are you using the latest AFNetworking framework?

Comment: yeah, you can check here https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.h

Comment: i think this answer is correct: our fork of clang is more strict than the iOS SDK's by default to catch these sorts of issues. this is likely something that should be addressed in AFNetworking's code.